# What is a better way to pass down a template to the component? As props or contents?

Tags: angular

Sometimes, we feel like passing down a piece of template to a component to make it reusable or customizable. We can achieve it either by passing template reference like:

```
// In a parent component
<ng-template #templateEx><p>I'm an example1</p></ng-template>
<theme-comp [template]="templateEx"></theme-comp>

// In a child(ThemeComponent) component
...
@Input() template: TemplateRef<any> // use it with ng-container
```

Or by projecting the template we want like:

```
// In a parent component
<theme-comp>
  <ng-template><p>I'm an example2</p></ng-template>
</theme-comp>

// In a child component
...
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any> // use it with ng-container
```

I think the both approaches would work perfectly fine but I'm just curious about the proper use cases for each one, or just differences. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: In my project we use second approach it's best method if you want your app more reusable because we want to avoid as much as possible passing down @Input variable since it's really hard to maintain

Comment: Did you try to use ``ng-content`` with ``select`` property? That's could be a simpler approach in my opinion, what you have to do is simply put your content inside component tag (``<app-component></app-component>``) and then use ``ng-content``.

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc I would go for the second approach as well but was just wondering if there's any pros to go with the first one

Comment: @Buczkowski If I would want to declare the content once at the parent component template and simply use it at the child component, I would go with the `ng-content` but I was thinking about more complex cases. Check out this article https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b

Comment: @Buczkowski Not about projecting contents, about templates